# jquery get ID of $(this).parent().parent().prev()

Tags: jquery

I have been able to get the correct output regarding an element i want to modify, but now i need to get the previous sibling's ID so i can perform an action on that one as well .. but i cant seem to get it working.

Javascript:

```
            $(".sort-up").click( function() {
                var curSel   = $(this).parent().parent();
                var curSelID = $(this).parent().parent().attr("id");
                var output = "You clicked on " + curSelID +  ".\n";
                var curSet   = curSelID.split("_");
                var curItem  = curSet[1];
                output = output + "The item ID for this is " + curItem +  ".\n";
                var classes  = $("#" + curSelID).attr("class");
                var classGrp = classes.split(" ");
                var type     = classGrp[classGrp.length - 1];
                output = output + "The Type is " + type +  ".\n";
                var index    = $(this).parent().parent().index("."+type);
                output = output + "The Index is " + index +  ".\n";
                if (index == 0) {
                    alert("Already at the top, can't move up.");
                } else {
                    alert(output);
                    var prevSel      = $("#" + curSelID).prev().attr("id");
                    output           = "Div ID to target is " + prevSel + "\n";
                    alert(output);
                }
            });
```

When I execute this script I get all the details about the "current" item i clicked on as follows:

```
You clicked on 2_3.
The item ID for this is 3.
The Type is Request.
The Index is 2.
```

html (:TLDR - just to show structure)

```
            <div class="requests" name="requests" id="requests">
                <div name="2_2" id="2_2" class="rowPri pl10 Request">
                    <div class="sortIcons">
                        <img class="sort-up" src="../images/sortOrderASC.png">
                        <img class="sort-down" src="../images/sortOrderDESC.png">
                        <div class="clr"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="req-title request-toggle">Create Public Facing Calendar</div>
                    <div class="req-status">Complete</div>
                    <div class="req-date">06-04-15</div>
                    <div class="clr"></div>
                    <div id="request_2_items" style="display:none;" class="pl45 items">
                        <div class="pl10 item ui-state-default Item" name="3_6" id="3_6">
                            <div class="sortIcons">
                                <img class="sort-up" src="../images/sortOrderASC.png">
                                <img class="sort-down" src="../images/sortOrderDESC.png">
                                <div class="clr"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item-details item-toggle">Connect PHP calendar to jCalPro back end</div>
                            <div class="item-status">Complete</div>
                            <div class="item-date">06-04-15</div>
                            <div class="clr"></div>
                            <div id="item_6_comments" style="display:none;" class="pl80 comments">
                                <div class="pl10">
                                    <div class="com-date">2015-06-04</div>
                                    <div class="com-com">Database connected </div>
                                    <div class="clr"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            <span class="divider"></span>
                <div name="2_8" id="2_8" class="rowPri pl10 Request">
                    <div class="sortIcons">
                        <img class="sort-up" src="../images/sortOrderASC.png">
                        <img class="sort-down" src="../images/sortOrderDESC.png">
                        <div class="clr"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="req-title request-toggle">Do Something</div>
                    <div class="req-status">Complete</div>
                    <div class="req-date">06-04-15</div>
                    <div class="clr"></div>
                    <div id="request_8_items" style="display: block;" class="pl45 items">
                        <div class="pl10 item ui-state-default Item" name="3_9" id="3_9">
                            <div class="sortIcons">
                                <img class="sort-up" src="../images/sortOrderASC.png">
                                <img class="sort-down" src="../images/sortOrderDESC.png">
                                <div class="clr"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item-details item-toggle">Do Part of something</div>
                            <div class="item-status">Complete</div>
                            <div class="item-date">06-04-15</div>
                            <div class="clr"></div>
                            <div id="item_9_comments" style="" class="pl80 comments">
                                <div class="pl10">
                                    <div class="com-date">2015-06-04</div>
                                    <div class="com-com">Did a little more</div>
                                    <div class="clr"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="pl10">
                                    <div class="com-date">2015-06-04</div>
                                    <div class="com-com">Did a little</div>
                                    <div class="clr"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pl10 item ui-state-default Item" name="3_10" id="3_10">
                            <div class="sortIcons">
                                <img class="sort-up" src="../images/sortOrderASC.png">
                                <img class="sort-down" src="../images/sortOrderDESC.png">
                                <div class="clr"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item-details item-toggle">Do more of part of something</div>
                            <div class="item-status">Complete</div>
                            <div class="item-date">06-04-15</div>
                            <div class="clr"></div>
                            <div id="item_10_comments" style="" class="pl80 comments">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            <span class="divider"></span>
                <div name="2_3" id="2_3" class="rowPri pl10 Request">
                    <div class="sortIcons">
                        <img class="sort-up" src="../images/sortOrderASC.png">
                        <img class="sort-down" src="../images/sortOrderDESC.png">
                        <div class="clr"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="req-title request-toggle">Create Event Addition page</div>
                    <div class="req-status">Complete</div>
                    <div class="req-date">06-04-15</div>
                    <div class="clr"></div>
                    <div id="request_3_items" style="display:none;" class="pl45 items">
                    </div>
                </div>
            <span class="divider"></span>
                <div name="2_4" id="2_4" class="rowPri pl10 Request">
                    <div class="sortIcons">
                        <img class="sort-up" src="../images/sortOrderASC.png">
                        <img class="sort-down" src="../images/sortOrderDESC.png">
                        <div class="clr"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="req-title request-toggle">Create Edit Event Page</div>
                    <div class="req-status">Complete</div>
                    <div class="req-date">06-04-15</div>
                    <div class="clr"></div>
                    <div id="request_4_items" style="display:none;" class="pl45 items">
                    </div>
                </div>
            <span class="divider"></span>
                <div name="2_5" id="2_5" class="rowPri pl10 Request">
                    <div class="sortIcons">
                        <img class="sort-up" src="../images/sortOrderASC.png">
                        <img class="sort-down" src="../images/sortOrderDESC.png">
                        <div class="clr"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="req-title request-toggle">Create Class Cards (Regiatration) page</div>
                    <div class="req-status">Complete</div>
                    <div class="req-date">06-04-15</div>
                    <div class="clr"></div>
                    <div id="request_5_items" style="display:none;" class="pl45 items">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Essentially, if i clicked on the div with the class ".request" numbered "2_3" I need to get the previous div with class ".request" which would be the div for for "2_8". I will then use this as an AJAX call to swap the order of these items in a Database, and then on the screen as well, but for the life of me I cant seem to get the id of the "previous" sibling div.

This same script would work on the class ".item" as well such as "3-10" needing to get the div ID of "3-9".  I am writing this script to work at either level so I don't have to write it twice.

I have researched .parent(), .prev(), etc.. and have not been able to get a working method.  Any help would be appreciated.

**Update 1:**

I tried to adapt the answer below to "move" the items, but it seems to kind of round robin the siblings above the one I clicked instead of just moving the one I clicked above its previous sibling. here is the Javascript I tried:

```
if (index == 0) {
    alert("This item is already top priority.");
} else {
    var swapSel   = curSel.siblings().prev(); 
    $(curSel).before($(swapSel));
}
```

**Update 2:**

I messed around with it and was able to get it to move the DIV in question above its "previous" sibling, without using the siblings() as that was jacking things up. I have completed the UP and DOWN moves with my existing HTML structure as seen above using the following Javascript:

```
$(".sort-up").click( function() {
    var curSel   = $(this).parent().parent();
    var curSelID = $(this).parent().parent().attr("id");
    var curSet   = curSelID.split("_");
    var curItem  = curSet[1];
    var classes  = $("#" + curSelID).attr("class");
    var classGrp = classes.split(" ");
    var type     = classGrp[classGrp.length - 1];
    var index    = curSel.index();
    if (index <= 0) {
        alert("This " + type + " is already highest priority.");
    } else {
        var swapSel   = curSel.prev(); 
        var swapSelID = swapSel.attr("id"); 
        $(curSel).insertBefore($(swapSel));
    }
});
$(".sort-down").click( function() {
    var curSel   = $(this).parent().parent();
    var curSelID = $(this).parent().parent().attr("id");
    var holder   = curSel.parent();
    var curSet   = curSelID.split("_");
    var curItem  = curSet[1];
    var classes  = $("#" + curSelID).attr("class");
    var classGrp = classes.split(" ");
    var type     = classGrp[classGrp.length - 1];
    var index    = curSel.index();
    var lastIndex = curSel.siblings().andSelf().length - 1;
    if (index >= lastIndex) {
        alert("This " + type + " is already lowest priority.");
    } else {
        var swapSel   = curSel.next(); 
        var swapSelID = swapSel.attr("id"); 
        $(curSel).insertAfter($(swapSel));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the siblings method to get the siblings of the your curSel object, then use the prev() method to get the one prior to your cur selection.  You can change it like so:

```
var prevSel      =  curSel.siblings().prev().attr('id');
```

[JS FIDDLE of your example](http://jsfiddle.net/sd4vjw5f/1)

Update:

for the changed question of the op:

your html is a little weird,  but this seems to do what you want.  I ended up having to use the id of the previous siblling to get the insertBefore (instead of before) to work.  also, you'll need to figure out what to do about those divider spans.  Also, you have nested items that could your not checking for being at the top of their nested hierarchy so youll need to deal with that.

`$(curSel).insertBefore($('#'+prevSel));`

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sd4vjw5f/2/)

Final Edit:

so it looks like the issue was a combination of those divider spans you were using and a stale element reference which is apparently a known bug in jquery.

if you resample the clicked element after moving the previous element, remove the original divider span separating them, and then add a new divider span after the now first element, it works as expected.  see my updated fiddle.

[THIS WAS ANNOYING](http://jsfiddle.net/sd4vjw5f/3/)

Comment: Well don't i feel like a heel.  I researched about siblings and then didn't even add it to the script ... works like a charm... thank you

Comment: turns out that doesn't quite do the trick .. it moves ALL the siblings above the one I click in a kind of rotation .. instead of moving just the one I clicked above it's previous sibling. still trying to figure out how to move just the one item above its previous sibling

Comment: see my updated answer.  hopefully this problem is solved for you as it seems there are potentially other issues in there that still need to be worked out :)

Comment: I tried insertBefore previously, but I thikn it duplicates the Div .. I will try again.

Comment: using the "sublings()" to get the ID and object actually makes the "insertbefore" execute on all of the siblings, not just the one prior to the selected object. so when i insert i get a copy of my selected div before every one of them. I will continue to work on this.

Comment: After playing around for a bit I have updated my question with the final code tha seems to be working.

Comment: @Silvertiger yeah, I've been looking at it a little closer, and those divider spans you have after each selection are messing up how siblings and prev work.  IF you put the divider spans inside of each element, my code should work as you like.  I was working on an update, but if you've got it working I'll stop :)

Comment: @Silvertiger also added colors to help demonstrate the final one works :)

Comment: Yes, even with the dividers I have found a solution that seems to work moving both up and down through the sibling Div's with Limits/alerts for top and bottom.  The code i am using is in the updated question. Thank you for your help